# Static utility class for string manipulation in C++

Tags: c++, strings, static

My programming foundations were formed in Java, but I've decided to only use C++ from now on for my projects as a personal learning experience. Static utility classes are common in Java; but I don't think they work the same as in C++. I'd like the following:

- Code review of the functions to determine potential function-specific improvements
- Analysis of the general architecture/structure to determine if static methods are the way to go. 
  If they are not, what would one recommend to achieve the desired result (which is to have a globally accessible set of utility methods)?

Here's the code:

### util.h

```cpp
#ifndef STDAFX_INCLUDE
#define STDAFX_INCLUDE

#include "stdafx.h"

#endif

#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm> 
#include <functional> 
#include <cctype>
#include <locale>
#include <random>

// Utility class to manage misc. functions

class Util {
public:
    static std::string serialize_http_args(std::map<std::string, std::string>);
    static std::string serialize_http_headers(std::map<std::string, std::string>);
    static int randrange(int min, int max);
    static void trim(std::string&);
    static void ltrim(std::string&);
    static void rtrim(std::string&);
    static std::string trim_copy(std::string);
    static std::string ltrim_copy(std::string);
    static std::string rtrim_copy(std::string);
    static std::string int2str(int);
    static std::string lowercase(std::string);
    static std::vector<std::string> split(std::string, std::string);
    static std::vector<std::string> split_once(std::string, std::string);
};
```

### util.c

````
#include "util.h"

// returns a random number in range min through max, inclusive.
int Util::randrange(int min, int max) {
    std::random_device rd; // obtain a random number from hardware
    std::mt19937 eng(rd()); // seed the generator
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distr(min, max); // define the range
    return distr(eng);
}

// takes a map of arguments and converts it to a string representation
std::string Util::serialize_http_args(std::map<std::string, std::string> _args) {
    if (_args.size() > 0) {
        size_t counter = 1;
        std::string args_str = "";
        for (auto const& arg : _args) {
            args_str += arg.first + "=" + arg.second;
            if (counter < _args.size())
                args_str += "&";
            counter++;
        }
        return args_str;
    }

    return "";
}

// takes a map of headers and converts it to the string representation
std::string Util::serialize_http_headers(std::map<std::string, std::string> _headers) {
    if (_headers.size() > 0) {
        std::string headers_ser = "";
        for (auto const& header : _headers)
            headers_ser += header.first + ": " + header.second + "\r\n";
        return (headers_ser + "\r\n");
    }

    return "";
}

// splits a string infinitely by delimiter until completely tokenized
std::vector<std::string> Util::split(std::string s, std::string delimiter) {
    std::vector<std::string> output;

    std::string::size_type prev_pos = 0, pos = 0;

    while ((pos = s.find(delimiter, pos)) != std::string::npos)
    {
        std::string substring(s.substr(prev_pos, pos - prev_pos));
        output.push_back(substring);
        prev_pos = ++pos;
    }

    output.push_back(s.substr(prev_pos, pos - prev_pos)); // Last word

    return output;
}

// splits a string by the first instance of delimiter
std::vector<std::string> Util::split_once(std::string s, std::string delimiter)
{
    std::vector<std::string> output;
    std::string::size_type pos = 0;

    if ((pos = s.find(delimiter, pos)) != std::string::npos) {
        output.push_back(std::string(s.substr(0, pos)));
        output.push_back(std::string(s.substr(pos + 1)));
    }

    return output;
}

// trim from start (in place)
void Util::ltrim(std::string & s) {
    s.erase(s.begin(), std::find_if(s.begin(), s.end(),
        std::not1(std::ptr_fun<int, int>(std::isspace))));
}

// trim from end (in place)
void Util::rtrim(std::string & s) {
    s.erase(std::find_if(s.rbegin(), s.rend(),
        std::not1(std::ptr_fun<int, int>(std::isspace))).base(), s.end());
}

// trim from both ends (in place)
void Util::trim(std::string & s) {
    ltrim(s);
    rtrim(s);
}

// trim from start (copying)
std::string Util::ltrim_copy(std::string _s) {
    std::string s = _s;
    ltrim(s);
    return s;
}

// trim from end (copying)
std::string Util::rtrim_copy(std::string _s) {
    std::string s = _s;
    rtrim(s);
    return s;
}

// trim from both ends (copying)
std::string Util::trim_copy(std::string _s) {
    std::string s = _s;
    trim(s);
    return s;
}

// convert string to lowercase version of same string
std::string Util::lowercase(std::string _s) {
    std::string s = _s;
    std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), ::tolower);
    return s;
}

//convert type integer to string
std::string Util::int2str(int i) {
    std::string out;
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << i;
    return ss.str();
}

```
````

Answer (score 7):

Your functions themselves are pretty broad, so I'm not going to review each one. However, I can tell you that what you're probably looking for is a `namespace`. A `namespace` is just a way to group together similar functions/classes/static objects. They're a little bit like Java's `package` in that they can be used to organize your code into related groups.

A class with only static functions can be converted to a namespace very easily:

```
#ifndef STDAFX_INCLUDE
#define STDAFX_INCLUDE

#include "stdafx.h"

#endif

#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm> 
#include <functional> 
#include <cctype>
#include <locale>
#include <random>

// Namespace containing utility functions

namespace Util {
    std::string serialize_http_args(std::map<std::string, std::string>);
    std::string serialize_http_headers(std::map<std::string, std::string>);
    int randrange(int min, int max);
    void trim(std::string&);
    void ltrim(std::string&);
    void rtrim(std::string&);
    std::string trim_copy(std::string);
    std::string ltrim_copy(std::string);
    std::string rtrim_copy(std::string);
    std::string int2str(int);
    std::string lowercase(std::string);
    std::vector<std::string> split(std::string, std::string);
    std::vector<std::string> split_once(std::string, std::string);
}
```

Note how `class` was changed to `namespace`, `public:` was removed (all items in a namespace are public), `static` was removed (it has different meaning outside of a class) and there is no semicolon after the final closing brace.

Each function is referenced the same as it was before, e.g. `int random = Util::randrange(0, 100)`.

Your include files also look strange compared to what you're actually using - based on the given function definitions, you should only need `<string>`, `<map>` and `<vector>` in this header. Best practice with include files is to *only* include the headers that you need for the current file. A user of this utility namespace doesn't care if your `randrange` function uses the `<random>` library for its implementation - that is a detail that should only appear in the source file.

As a side note, since it looks like you're developing on Windows, best practice is to put

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

as the first line in every *source* file, and leave it out of your *header* files completely. See [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5234347/8365363) for more details.

Comment: Thank you. I did not know that about the includes, I thought best practice was to put all includes in the header file. But that makes sense. With regards to stdafx. I've seen several different answers about when/how/bestpractices for stdafx. Could you update your answer to explain how it would apply in this case?

Comment: @leaustinwile I've updated my post with a link to a relevent StackOverflow answer, and added some more information about namespaces at the beginning.

Comment: For sake of brevity and clarity, would you recommend against using stdafx? This is intended to be a cross-platform project upon completion. Operable on at the minimum, linux and windows.

Comment: @leaustinwile That depends on your project. `stdafx` represents the concept of precompiled headers, which can be used to drastically improve compilation time for a large project. The idea is that you put all commonly-used headers into `stdafx.h`, which is then precompiled and cached, reducing the cost of subsequent compilations. The trade-off is that you lose the ability to see, at a glance, the dependencies for each file in your project (since common library includes are extracted to `stdafx.h`). If your compilation time isn't a big issue, then precompiled headers probably aren't necessary.

Comment: No. This will probably be a small to medium sized project upon completion. I don't think that compilation time will be a problem. I'm going to remove it for clarity sake. I just thought I'd use it in the beginning because I wanted to try out new C++ features I've never used! :)

Comment: Also, what is the benefit of using a namespace vs. the static class I wrote? Functionally it seems the same, but what's happening in the compiler?

Comment: @leaustinwile Functionally (and as far as the compiler is concerned), a class with only static methods is equivalent to a namespace. The biggest advantage you gain here is intent. Classes are used to create objects. A class with only static methods is [surprising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment), because you would never create an object out of that class. In Java, we use static utility classes to convey the intent of "this is a grouping of related items, which cannot be instantiated". In C++, this purpose is served by `namespace`.

Answer (score 5):

- In `randrange`, you initialize the random device, the engine, and the distribution on every call. So this is not suitable for every situation, i.e., when performance matters.
- In `serialize_http_args` and in general, **never** query the size of a container when you want to determine whether it is empty or not. For that, you should use `empty()`. This is idiomatic and saves you from costly surprises like with container implementations where `empty()` is a constant time method while `size()` needs linear time.
- At least for both `serialize_http_args` and `serialize_http_headers`, you might consider first checking whether `_args.empty()` (or `_headers.empty()`), and then returing an empty string, i.e.,:

  ```
  std::string serialize_http_args(std::map<std::string, std::string> _args) 
  {
      if (_args.empty())
          return "";

      size_t counter = 1;
      std::string args_str = "";
      for (auto const& arg : _args) 
      {
          args_str += arg.first + "=" + arg.second;
          if (counter < _args.size())
              args_str += "&";
          counter++;
      }

      return args_str;
  }
  ```

  I find this cleaner and easier to read, especially if the functions were any longer.
- You don't need your own `int2str` anymore, you can just use [`std::to_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string).

Comment: Good points. I'm still learning all the methods and functions I have available so I've just been hacking it together with my Java/Python know-how. Could you clarify on constant vs. linear time methods/functions and what they are?

Comment: @leaustinwile Sure. For example [the `size` method of `std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/size) could have been a linear-time method pre-C++11. IIRC, this had something to do with splicing then.

Answer (score 2):

The function for serializing URL parameters is horribly broken since it leaves out URL escaping. Don't invent these functions yourself. Since you're from a Java background, have a look at Apache Commons and Spring Framework, they already implemented this function and took care about all edge cases.

There's probably a C++ library that provides URL encoding. You're definitely not the first one to need this function in a C++ program.